# View Page Source in Full Screen Mobile Safari - iPad

Tags: ipad, mobile-safari

Is there anyway to view the source of a web page on mobile Safari in iPad via the home screen app button? because this obviously hides the address bar etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can't view source in Mobile Safari full-stop.

**EDIT**
Have you checked out the remote debugging tools that are out there? Whilst you won't necessarily be abel to view full-screen web app source on the device itself, you may then be able to view the source on the control device. For example, [weinre](https://github.com/apache/incubator-cordova-weinre)

Comment: I believe you can: http://banagale.com/view-source-from-safari-on-ipad.htm - I have this working, was just wondering if there was a sneaky way to do it in full screen app mode.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is that if you are a developer you can install firebug light on your page .

It will make the dev. much easier ... you only have acccess to (CONSOLE - HTML - CSS - SCRIPT - DOM)

More info here :

https://getfirebug.com/firebuglite#Install

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, nitro html and WebInspector are both apps that allow you to view and in the case of nitro html edit the source html of a webpage

Answer (score 0):

I am able to view the source of a web page (though it looks pretty ugly) on my iphone. I found a tip on the net. Pretty simple.

1. Go to any webpage
2. Tap add bookmark
3. In the name section add anything you like
4. In the address field add this:
   `javascript:(function()%7Bvar%20a=window.open('about:blank').document;a.write('%3C!DOCTYPE%20html%3E%3Chtml%3E%3Chead%3E%3Ctitle%3ESource%20of%20'+location.href+'%3C/title%3E%3Cmeta%20name=%22viewport%22%20content=%22width=device-width%22%20/%3E%3C/head%3E%3Cbody%3E%3C/body%3E%3C/html%3E');a.close();var%20b=a.body.appendChild(a.createElement('pre'));b.style.overflow='auto';b.style.whiteSpace='pre-wrap';b.appendChild(a.createTextNode(document.documentElement.innerHTML))%7D)();` [image]
5. That is it. Now open the site you want to see the source of.
6. Go to bookmarks and tap the one you created. It will open the source in a new tab.

[image]

[image]
Tell me if it worked for you :)